# Partial implementation of an interface

Tags: java

Having only a small amount of time to search for such things, I could not see anything that covered my specific scenario.

I am working with a 3rd party interface.  Let us say for a moment it is as follows:

```
    public interface interface1
    {
        public String getVar1();

        public void  method1();

        public void method2();

    }
```

I need to create a number of classes that make use of this interface but the actual method implementation of "method2" would differ on each,where as "method1" and "getVar1" would always be the same code.

Is there any way to create an abstract base class that implements the interface but only forces the implementation of "method2" onto the child classes?

I had tried

```
public abstract @Override void method2
```

but while this is "acceptable" at design time in Netbeans (don't know if Eclipse acts differently) at compile time it complains that method2 needs to be implemented.

If it is not possible, fair enough, I just need to check.

thanks

Comment: You need to declare your *class* abstract and leave out any implementation of `method2`

Comment: Here is the same question for `Kotlin`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362581/can-i-omit-the-interface-methods-i-do-not-use-in-kotlin

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this by creating an abstract class that implements the interface.  Any sub-class of this abstract class will be required to implement any interface methods that were not yet defined.

```
public abstract class AbstractInterface implements interface1 {
    @Override
    public String getVar1() {

    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {

    }
}
```

```
public class Implementation extends AbstractInterface {
    @Override
    public void method2() {

    }
}
```

See: [Java tutorial on abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can create an abstract class which does not implement `method2()`

```
public abstract class AbstractImplementation implements interface1 {
    public String getVar1() { 
      // implementation ..
    }

    public void  method1() {
      // implementation ..
    }

    // skip method2
}
```

Then create multiple implementations:

```
public class Implementation1 extends AbstractImplementation {
    public void method2() {
      // implementation 1
    }
} 

public class Implementation2 extends AbstractImplementation {
    public void method2() {
      // implementation 2
    }
}

...
```

Comment: He is talking about third party interface.If the code in thirdparty program is void(interface1 test){
test.getVar1(); // not able to call this  service 
}

Comment: Ups, I forgot to add `implements interface1`. Corrected this. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `abstract Class` that provides implementation for "method 1" and "getVar1" but `decalre method2 as abstract` in this Class.

Now Inherit this Abstract Super Class in all your other Classes!

Like

```
public interface interface1 {

    public void getVar1();

    public void method1();

    public void method2();

}

public abstract class test implements interface1 {

    @Override
    public void getVar1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public abstract void method2();


}

public class test1 extends test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have 3 abstract methods in the interface you can override one or two methods and other methods will remain as abstract

```
abstact class PartialImplementationDemo implements interface1 {
  @Override
  public void method1() {
    // override method1() here
  }

  // leave other methods as abstract
  abstract public void method2();
  abstract public String getVar1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface I1
{
    public void  Method1();
    public void Method2();
}
abstract class A implements I1
{
    public void Method1()
    {
         System.out.println("In  Method 1");
    }

    abstract public void Method3();
}
class B extends A    //Inherits class A 
{
    public void Method2()
    {
         System.out.println("In Method 2");
    }
    public void Method3()
    {
         System.out.println("In Method 3");
    }
}
public class Main 
    {
     public static void main(String args[])
        {
            B b1=new B();
            b1.Method1();
            b1.Method2();
            b1.Method3();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Output will be:In Method 1 In Method 2 In Method 3

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some info on how to apply this code.